# Borrar espacio en blanco al final del archivo (.txt)

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, archivo

Tengo un código donde hago una consulta con php y sql server, la consulta me trae ciertos registros, luego creo un archivo tipo texto (.TXT) y con un ciclo `while(true)` escribo los registros y cuando ya no hay registros que escribir le doy la orden `break` para que pare el ciclo.

El asunto es que para poder diferenciar un registro de otro escribo un `"\r\n"`
para saltar a la siguiente linea y que escriba el registro que sigue.

Los registros me los escribe bien en el archivo(.TXT) justo como lo necesito

¿Cual es el problema?

Cuando escribe el ultimo registro me deja una linea en blanco al final.

Obviamente el espacio en blanco es a causa de colocar ``"\r\n"` pero si no lo coloco me va a escribir todos los registros en linea recta, sin saltar linea

Habra una forma de borrar ese espacio que queda al final del archivo o hay alguna manera de hacer el salto de linea entre registros sin que me deje ese espacio.

Este es el codigo de cuando hago el salto de linea:

```
$notas = "";

$notas_completo = str_pad($notas, 255,  " ", STR_PAD_RIGHT);

fwrite($ruta, $notas_completo."\r\n");
```

Basicamente en la variable `$notas` cargo el dato que voy escribir y en `fwrite` para insertar, asi inserto todos los datos, y si se fijan en el `fwrite` coloco el `"\r\n"` ya que `$notas` es el ultimo dato, pueden ignorar el `str_pad` solo lo uso para rellenar espacio por si al registro le faltan caracteres.

Este es el espacio en blanco que me deja en el archivo `(.TXT)`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Actualización:
Yo se que en este archivo `(.TXT)` queda algo así como un espacio que indica el fin del fichero, mi consulta solo tiene 100 registros ya contados, y como se fijan en el pantallazo  que adjunto, no dice 100 lineas, dice 101
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si yo borro la linea 101 y guardo ya me queda como debería quedar, con 100 lineas

Comment: No hay un espacio en blanco.. hay un eof que tiene que estar si o si..miralo en hexadecimal y te vas a dar cuenta.

Comment: @gbianchi  tiene razón, acabo de revisar algunos procesos que me generan ".txt" y todos dejan ese salto al final, pero eso en ningún caso me ha significado un error al momento de leerlos desde otro proceso.

Comment: sera un error del proceso que lee este?

Comment: La verdad este archivo va a ser leído por un programa y no se si pueda generar algún error y si es así voy a seguir con el problema

Comment: @gbianchi cuando dices "eof" y que tiene que estar si o si, pero en el eof no se puede escribir mas, no? si estoy en un error aca acaba la consulta y estaba equivocado con mi duda entonces

Comment: Eof es end of file. Y esta siempre. Si no como sabe cuando se acaba el archivo?

Comment: Lo que no está claro es: ¿qué falla con el formato actual del archivo? ¿falla algo al leerlo?

Answer (score 1):

Lo que podés hacer es no escribir el último `\r\n`

Algo así:

```
$endofline = "";
while(true) {

  $notas_completo = str_pad($notas, 255,  " ", STR_PAD_RIGHT);

  // al escribir la primer línea $endofline es una cadena vacía
  fwrite($ruta, $endofline . $notas_completo);

  // para la segunda línea y subsecuentes se inserta un retorno de carro + nuevalínea
  $endofline = "\r\n";

  if ($algo) break;
}
```